# postgresql insert or create with temp table merge

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables: `A` `B` and `C`. `B` is a `TEMP TABLE` created from the output of a `CSV`. My goal is to copy the necessary values from `B` to `A` *but* one of the attributes has to be created or selected from `C`.

So far I have

```
WITH table_c_data as (
  INSERT INTO table_c (id)
  SELECT table_c_id
  FROM table_b b
  WHERE 
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_c c WHERE b.table_c_id = c.id)
  RETURNING *
)

INSERT INTO table_a
(w,x,y,z)
SELECT table_c.id, x, y, z
FROM table_b
INNER JOIN table_c_data as table_c
ON table_b.table_c_id = table_c.id;
```

but I am having trouble figuring out how to have the original `table_c_data` return anything if the record *does* existing. (Before I added in the `WHERE` clause specifying existing the query ran as expected, but I am trying to handle uniquness constraints so I have to check whether the record exists first)

Comment: I've read your question about 5 times, and I still don't understand what you are trying to do and what the issue is. Maybe it's me. Willing to help if I can understand the question.

Comment: I have three tables: A, B, and C. I need to copy some of the data from table B to table A *but* I also need to either pull an id from table C or create a new record altogether using an attribute that exists on table B.

Comment: If you want to copy the data into table `table_a` then why are you doing an insert into `table_c`?

Comment: a foreign key in `table_a` is created by inserting a record to `table_c` that depends on values in `table_b`